# Find Mail Sent from Account on CentOS 5.4

Tags: email, centos

A client of ours was sending out a mass e-mail to their membership. The process crashed midway. They'd like to resume the mass e-mail but so far I haven't been able to figure out where to look.

Problem: the mail is sent iteratively by a PHP script. This script doesn't track it's progress. I'm a PHP developer with little server knowledge.

**What I was hoping to do was inspecting the mail server and asking "What's the last e-mail newsletter@domain.com sent?"**

The server is running a fairly vanilla CentOS 5.4 install.

I'm not sure what mail server software it's running, if someone can instruct me how to identify this, I will post it.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try running `grep` on /var/log/maillog for the email address to see what's been happening, maybe with a pipe through `tail` to trim down the output to the most recent few entries.

The default install of CentOS typically includes Sendmail; `rpm -q sendmail` will confirm this.